# How to pass a second parameter using .htaccess to a php code?

Tags: php, json, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm writing my api using friendly urls with .htaccess to do the redirects.

When I need to pass a second parameter, I'm having problems

My .htaccesss file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^mesas\/?([0-9]+)\/?(.+)\/?$ mesas.php?status=$1
RewriteRule ^statusmesa\/?([0-9]+)\/?(.+)\/?$ statusmesa.php?idmesa=$1&status=$2
```

When I use the call to statusmesa using `statusmesa/2/3`, it returns as the first parameter `2` and as second `3.php/2/3`

What's wrong with my rule?

Note that the file .htaccss has multiple rules for multiple routes

Comment: They should all be in the `$_GET` array of a PHP file.

Comment: No, the first and the second argument use $_GET to $var, i don't use an array

Comment: If you are calling `statusmesa/2/3`, from where `3.php` got attached for the rewriting? Also, your rules don't have an `[L]` flag to stop processing the rule set?

Comment: Like this:`RewriteRule ^statusmesa\/?([0-9]+)\/?(.+)\/?$ statusmesa.php?idmesa=$1&status=$2 [L]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved !

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$  /$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^mesas\/?([0-9]*)?$ mesas.php?status=$1
RewriteRule ^statusmesa/([0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ statusmesa.php?idmesa=$1&status=$2 [NC]
```